# How to extract all names in a R list along with the column header names of matrixes embedded in that list?

Tags: r, list

Suppose we have the list object `list_tmp` generated with the code posted at the bottom. How do I extract all list names, as well as the column header names of matrixes embedded in that list? The image below shows what I'm trying to do.

Sublist `list_tmp$Top$One` has an embedded 3-column matrix with headers A, B, and Total; sublist `list_tmp$Top$Two` has a 2-column matrix with headers A and Total.

I'm trying to avoid a for-loop, and also would rather do this in base R but if not possible one of the super-standard packages like dplyr would be fine too if base R is onerous. I'm trying to avoid package bloat.

Here's the image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The code to generate `list_tmp` example:

```
list_tmp <- list(
  Top = list(
    One = matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=3,dimnames = list(NULL,c("A","B","Total"))),
    Two = matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("A","Total")))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gsub` + `as.data.frame` (if you consider 3-level nested list)

```
> gsub("(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)", "$\\1$\\2_\\3", names(as.data.frame(list_tmp)))
[1] "$Top$One_A"     "$Top$One_B"     "$Top$One_Total" "$Top$Two_A"
[5] "$Top$Two_Total"
```

---

Or make it more general, i.e., more levels

```
sub(
    "\\$(\\w+)$",
    "_\\1",
    gsub(".",
        "$",
        paste0("$", names(as.data.frame(list_tmp))),
        fixed = TRUE
    )
)
```

Comment: I do love how concise this is.  Am I right in saying it's specific to the three-levels list structure as presented in the question (i.e. a fourth level would not get the desired treatment)?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen you are right, it applies to three levels only

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen See my update

Comment: Maybe it can also be generalized using `gsubfn` library. Maybe @G. Grothendieck can enlighten us here

Comment: @Sotos I guess my latter option can generalize :P

Comment: Yes, I saw it as soon as I pressed enter on the comment :)

Comment: Good update, very handy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rapply` in base R like so to recursively apply a function:

```r
lnm <- rapply(list_tmp, colnames)
paste0(names(lnm), "_", lnm)
#[1] "Top.One1_A"     "Top.One2_B"     "Top.One3_Total" "Top.Two1_A"     "Top.Two2_Total"
```

And then some `gsub` regex machinery to get the expected output:

```r
gsub("(.*)\\.([A-Za-z]+)\\d+(.*)", "$\\1$\\2\\3", nm_raw)
#[1] "$Top$One_A"     "$Top$One_B"     "$Top$One_Total" "$Top$Two_A"     "$Top$Two_Total"
```

Comment: right...I was doing `rapply(list_tmp, names)` and I was getting NULL so I was building a recursive function from scratch which was breaking cause again I used `names` instead of `colnames`...<FACEPALM>

Comment: This is nice! +1

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Mael is the best here, but since I already created an old school recursive function I thought to share it as well,

```
my_fun <- function(lst) {
  lapply(lst, \(i) {
    if (is.list(i)) {
      my_fun(i)
    } else {
      colnames(i)
    }
  })
}

i1 <- unlist(my_fun(list_tmp))

paste0(names(i1), '_', i1)
# [1] "Top.One1_A"     "Top.One2_B"     "Top.One3_Total" "Top.Two1_A"     "Top.Two2_Total"
```

Comment: I am a fan of recursion, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
list_tmp$Top <- lapply(seq_along(list_tmp$Top), FUN = \(i) {
  pref <- names(list_tmp$Top)[i]
  suff <- colnames(list_tmp$Top[i][[1]])
  idents <- paste0(pref, "_", suff)
  sapply(idents, list)
}) |> unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

Gives you:

```
$Top
$Top$One_A
[1] "One_A"

$Top$One_B
[1] "One_B"

$Top$One_Total
[1] "One_Total"

$Top$Two_A
[1] "Two_A"

$Top$Two_Total
[1] "Two_Total"
```

Edit: having seen the other answer, I misunderstood the desired output - I thought it was a list structure but it should be a vector of strings - I will amend.

Amended:

```
charvec <- sapply(seq_along(list_tmp$Top), FUN = \(i) {
  pref <- names(list_tmp$Top)[i]
  suff <- colnames(list_tmp$Top[i][[1]])
  idents <- paste0("$Top$", pref, "_", suff)
}) |> unlist()

> charvec
[1] "$Top$One_A"     "$Top$One_B"     "$Top$One_Total" "$Top$Two_A"     "$Top$Two_Total"
```

Comment: What If there are other sublists that are NOT called `Top`?

Comment: @Sotos You're correct - this is specific only to the exact example above.  I went for an easily-readable solution but a more robust generic one would likely be a better choice (I like your recursive approach myself).

Comment: I think you should be able to map the list names via `names(list_tmp)`